# Mock base class method with Easymock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I have the following test code:

```
    herder = PowerMock.createPartialMock(DistributedHerder.class, new String[]{"backoff", "updateDeletedConnectorStatus"},
            new DistributedConfig(HERDER_CONFIG), worker, WORKER_ID, statusBackingStore, configBackingStore, member, MEMBER_URL, time);

    configUpdateListener = herder.new ConfigUpdateListener();
    rebalanceListener = herder.new RebalanceListener();
    plugins = PowerMock.createMock(Plugins.class);
    EasyMock.expect(worker.getPlugins()).andReturn(plugins);
    EasyMock.expect(herder.connectorType(CONN1)).andReturn(ConnectorType.SOURCE).anyTimes();
```

where connectorType() method is defined in AbstractHerder, base class of DistributedHerder.
Since the herder is created off of DistributedHerder, easy mock doesn't find mock for AbstractHerder class, leading to NPE:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerderTest > testInconsistentConfigs FAILED
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.getConnector(AbstractHerder.java:342)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$af0dd240.CGLIB$getConnector$39(<generated>)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$af0dd240$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8c31132d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.easymock.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$af0dd240.getConnector(<generated>)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.connectorType(AbstractHerder.java:349)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$af0dd240.CGLIB$connectorType$23(<generated>)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$af0dd240$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8c31132d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.easymock.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$af0dd240.connectorType(<generated>)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerderTest.setUp(DistributedHerderTest.java:179)
```

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: Where are you calling `reply` on `herder`?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit lost here but will still try to give some hints in terms of Socratic questions.

- Why do you need PowerMock for `DistributedHerder`? It looks like a normal partial mocking
- And why PowerMock for `Plugins` instead of plain EasyMock?
- Do you have the PowerMock runner configured?
- What is `herder.new ConfigUpdateListener()`? Which language is that?
- What is `worker`?
- I see no `replay()` indeed. Can we have the full code?
- Nothing is recorded for `backoff` and `updateDeletedConnectorStatus`. Is that normal?
- In your case, it seems the `plugins()` method is returning null. This one isn't mocked so it probably just return null indeed no?